# regex issue in making a markdown parser

Tags: python, regex, markdown

I'm trying to make a markdown parser in python, not because it's useful but because it's fun and because I'm trying to learn regular expression.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

class Converter:

    def markdown2html(self, string):

        string = re.sub('\*{3}(.+)\*{3}', '<strong>\\1</strong>', string)
        string = re.sub('\*{2}(.+)\*{2}', '<i>\\1</i>', string)
        string = re.sub('^#{1}(.+)$', '<h1>\\1</h1>', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        string = re.sub('^#{2}(.+)$', '<h2>\\1</h2>', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)

        return string

markdown_sting = """
##h2 heading
#H1 heading
This should be a ***bold*** char
#anohter h1
anohter ***bold***
this is a **italic** string
"""

converter = Converter()
print converter.markdown2html(markdown_sting)
```

It prints

```
<h1>#h2 heading</h1>
<h1>H1 heading</h1>
This should be a <strong>bold</strong> char
<h1>anohter h1</h1>
anohter <strong>bold</strong>
this is a <i>italic</i> string
```

As you can see it does not parse the h2 tag. Where I went wrong?

Comment: by the time you're starting to "parse" `h2` tag, its line has already been parsed by the `h1` rule.

Comment: If you _really_ want to learn regex, read: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!"). But for now, you can get a good start by reading [the Python Standard Library re docs](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/re.html). (You should be using raw strings to store your patterns.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make sure to only match the wanted number of hash signs by making sure that the first character of the heading text *isn't* a hash sign. This can be done by using `[^#]` like this:

```
string = re.sub('^#{1}([^#].*)$', '<h1>\\1</h1>', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
string = re.sub('^#{2}([^#].*)$', '<h2>\\1</h2>', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

This way the order of the rules won't matter, making the rules more robust.

Answer (score 4):

when you parser sees `#`, it does the substitution for `h1`.  Then it tries to do the substitution for `h2`, but there are not strings `##` since one of the hashes (`'#'`) was already replaced when parsing the `h1` portion.

A simple fix is to exchange the order:

```
string = re.sub('^#{2}(.+)$', '<h2>\\1</h2>', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
string = re.sub('^#{1}(.+)$', '<h1>\\1</h1>', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

In general, when you're applying transforms to data, you should order it from *most restrictive to least restrictive* in order to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Those regexes are evaluated in order. The h1 regex will grab any line beginning with a # and convert it to `<h1>`. So by the time it gets to the h2 regex, the line no longer begins with ##. Swap those two expressions around.

Answer (score 1):

A more appropriate and more efficient method may be to compare the first characters of the string, and then perform a simple string replace

```
def markdown2html(self, string):

    if string[0:2] == "##":
        string = string.replace( "##", "<h2>" ) + "</h2>"
    if string[0] == "#":
        string = string.replace( "##", "<h1>" ) + "</h1>"
    return string
```

That way you are doing simple list manipulation rather than RegEx. But in all cases, order matters

Comment: You could use [`startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) instead of slicing ...